# NLP. Split sentence into parts

Tags: nlp

Good example of what I want to do is lingvolive.com. When you type your sentence it shows to you translation of each part of sentence.

**Screenshot of lingvolive**
[image: abc]

There is a sentence: `"Never give up!"` and I want to split in into parts `["never", "give up"]`. Or `"Consider the larger picture beyond narrowly focused goal"` into `["Consider", "the", "larger picture", "beyond", "narrowly", "focused" ,"goal"]`

For this task I have big labeled database parsed from englishcentral.com. ([Example](http://www.englishcentral.com/api/bridge/content/dialog/26882?complete=true&siteLanguage=en)) There for every word/phrase specified its part of speech.

It's no matter it's a phrasal verb or idiom, I just need to extract groups of words from sentence.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any nlp library like nltk or opennlp to train your model.
you already have the tagged dataset so it's not a tough task.
If you wish to use [Opennlp](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html), it's quite easy to train your model. you can simply follow this [blog](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-sentence-detector-training.html) to get started. There's a lot of basic support there.

Hope this helps.